# Laravel 5.8 Save API data to Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

I want to store data form a third party api into my database, sounds pretty basic but im kinda confused.

I have this in my Controller

```
public function showTips()
    {
        $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]); 
        $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/api/xxx/xxxapiKey=xxxx');
        $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());
        $events = $data->Data;
        dd($events);
        //return view('tips')->with(compact('events'));               
    }
```

And the data i got:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#8824 ▼
    +"timeLive": "76"
    +"matchID": "10482C5"
```

What changes I have to do to just receive the "timeLive" data and store it on a MySQL table?
Every help will be appreciated!

Comment: How does the table look like? In which column do you want to store the `timeLive` values?

Comment: I created a table "ApiData" with fields: id, timevalue, ... etc

Comment: And what is "..."? Should the other coumns be empty/NULL?

Comment: There are more columns for other api data, they should be empty/NULL too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should loop foreach result like this :

```
$data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(),true);
    $events = $data['Data'];
foreach($events as $item)
{
 DB::table('your_table')->insert(['timeLive'=>$item['timeLive']])
}
```

witch timeLive is column in your table "your_table"

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: `DB::table('your_table')->insert(['timeLive'=>$item->timeLive])`

Comment: I got another error: syntax error, unexpected ''timeLive'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: it saves! but now the problem is it duplicates when i request the API data! I mean the table field is created again and again. Also I want a recommendation: The 'my_table' table data have to be updated at the same time as the Api data, I mean updated at least every minute. Should i work this code on my view controller? Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, how to call this item? `"homeTeamInfo": {
        "homeTeam": "GNK Dinamo Zagreb"`

Answer (score 0):

The following will insert `timeLive` values into the `timevalue` column:

```
\DB::table('my_table')->insert(collect($events)->map(function($item) {
    return ['timevalue' => $item->timeLive];
}));
```